# Find whether the following set of continuous differentiable functions forms a Vector Space over the set of real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ = {$f$, such that $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f$ is continuous and differentiable, and $f(x) = 0$ at a finite number of points in $[0,1]$}. Is $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

From my understanding, $\forall f, g \in V$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$,

$f + g \in V (\because(f + g)(x) = f (x) + g (x) \in V, \forall x \in [0,1])$

$cf \in V (\because (c.f)(x) = c.f(x) \in V, \forall x \in [0,1])$

Please help with this question. I don't know how to proceed with the information given regarding $f(x) = 0$ at finite points. How is that relevant to this question?

Comment: A vector space must contain the zero vector. See if this helps

Comment: Oh correct! The identity element would have to be f, such that $f(x) = 0 \forall x$. But that would mean infinite zeroes and that would go against the definition of f. Thanks for the hint @moboDawn_φ